# How to write Pester tests for my PowerShell function

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have the following function:
For this function I'm required to write a Pester code that will have 100% coverage.

```
function buildFilterString {
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [string] $input_str, 
    [char] $delimiter
)

$out = $null

$input_str -split $delimiter | ForEach-Object {
    $item = $_
    $out += "'" + $item + "',"
}

$out.Substring(0,$out.Length-1)
}
```

As I understood the test should look like this, but I'm not sure how to write the "different cases" in the test.

```
$moduleRoot = Resolve-Path "$PSScriptRoot\.."
$moduleName = Split-Path $moduleRoot -Leaf
$cred = Get-Credential

Describe "Demonstarting Code Coverage of: $moduleName" {

 It "Calls Function: builedFilterString" {
    {buildFilterString -input_str "happy" -delimiter ';'} | Should Be 
     "happy"
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this your homework?  Seems you've got a few very [similar tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56223485/writing-tests-for-powershell-functions/56224037) to perform.  You should read the [Pester documentation](https://github.com/pester/Pester/wiki) which details how different types of tests are constructed, then (as I recommended last time), think hard about the intended behaviour of your function and write appropriate tests for that behaviour.

Comment: Describe = Module, Context = function of module, It = different cases to test the function of the module

Answer (score 0):

In this case you just need to make sure the `-input_str` contains the specified `-delimiter` and all you're code is covered. You could keep the stated case were the `-input_str` does not contain the specified `-delimiter`, to test the edge case (which will fail by the way, because `$out` will stay `$null`).